# How to remove duplicate values on google data studio

Tags: duplicates, looker-studio

I have a dimension (a column from google sheets) called products with the following values:

```
product = [apple , apple_old_2019, pineapple , pineapple_old_2020, pineapple_old_2017 ...]
```

I need to regex then and remove the pattern `old_****` and then aggregate the values by name.

In Google Sheets I would replace the values and then use the Unique formula, but in Google Data Studio there isn't such function.

I created a custom field called Product_pre with this formula:

`REGEXP_EXTRACT(Product , '^(.+?)(_old_[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{4})' )`

Then I created another custom field with the following formula:

```
CASE
    WHEN Product_pre_process is null THEN Product
    ELSE Product_pre_process 
END
```

The problem is that the result has duplicated values:

```
product_processed = [apple , apple, pineapple , pineapple, pineapple ...]
```

How could I fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1) Extract the First Word**
The [`REGEXP_EXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7050487) function below does the trick (extracting all the characters from the beginning of each string till the first instance of `_`):

```
REGEXP_EXTRACT(Product , "^([^_]*)")
```

**2) Consolidation**
If the chart type is a [Table](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7189044), then removing the rest of the dimensions and leaving just the newly created dimension will result in the metric values automatically aggregating based on the two values in the dimension (`apple` and `pineapple`).

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/bfd1e52d-0106-443f-b9b6-60a1c3897699) as well as a GIF to visualise the above:

[image]